# Gstreamer of python's gst.LinkError problem

Tags: python, gstreamer

I am wiring a gstreamer application with Python.  And I get a LinkError with following code:

```
import pygst
pygst.require('0.10')
import gst

import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

# this is very important, without this, callbacks from gstreamer thread
# will messed our program up
gtk.gdk.threads_init()

def main():
    pipeline = gst.Pipeline('pipleline')

    filesrc = gst.element_factory_make("filesrc", "filesrc")
    filesrc.set_property('location', 'C:/a.mp3')

    decode = gst.element_factory_make("decodebin", "decode")

    convert = gst.element_factory_make('audioconvert', 'convert')

    sink = gst.element_factory_make("autoaudiosink", "sink")

    pipeline.add(filesrc, decode, convert, sink)
    gst.element_link_many(filesrc, decode, convert, sink)

    pipeline.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)

    gtk.main()

main()
```

And the error:

```
ImportError: could not import gio
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\workspace\ggg\src\test2.py", line 37, in <module>
    main()
  File "H:\workspace\ggg\src\test2.py", line 31, in main
    gst.element_link_many(filesrc, decode, convert, sink)
gst.LinkError: failed to link decode with convert
```

It is very strange, with same pipeline, but built with parse_launch, it works. Here is the code:

```
import pygst
pygst.require('0.10')
import gst

import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

# this is very important, without this, callbacks from gstreamer thread
# will messed our program up
gtk.gdk.threads_init()

def main():
    player = gst.parse_launch('filesrc location=C:/a.mp3 ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! autoaudiosink') 
    player.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)
    gtk.main()

main()
```

Here comes the question, why the manual one failed, but the parsed one success?  What's wrong with that?  How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: for the record, i don't get the first error you have listed: "ImportError: could not import gio". i do get the rest of them, though, see below

Answer (score 21, accepted):

your problem is here:

```
gst.element_link_many(filesrc, decode, convert, sink)
```

the reason is that not all elements have simple, static inputs and outputs. at this point in your program, *your decodebin does not have any source pads* (that is: no outputs).

a pad is like a nipple - it's an input / output to an element. pads can appear, disappear or just sit there. there are three classes of pads: *static pads* (the easiest and what you would expect), *request pads* (that appear only when you ask for them) and *sometimes pads* (that appear only when the element wants to make them appear). the outputs of `decodebin` are *sometimes pads*.

if you inspect the output of `gst-inspect decodebin`, you can see this for yourself:

```
Pad Templates:
  SINK template: 'sink'
    Availability: Always
    Capabilities:
      ANY

  SRC template: 'src%d'
    Availability: Sometimes
    Capabilities:
      ANY
```

at line 26 of your program, you can't link decode to anything, because it doesn't have any source pads to link with. source pads on a decodebin appear only as the input stream is decoded: this doesn't happen instantaneously. any number of source pads may appear (e.g one for an audio stream, two for a video stream with audio, none for an un-decodable stream).

you need to wait until the pads are created, and then link them. decodebin emits a signal, "new-decoded-pad" to tell you when this happens (this is also documented in `gst-inspect decodebin`). you must connect a callback function to this signal, and link your decode and audioconvert in the callback. here is your corrected code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pygst
pygst.require('0.10')
import gst

import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

# this is very important, without this, callbacks from gstreamer thread
# will messed our program up
gtk.gdk.threads_init()

def on_new_decoded_pad(dbin, pad, islast):
    decode = pad.get_parent()
    pipeline = decode.get_parent()
    convert = pipeline.get_by_name('convert')
    decode.link(convert)
    pipeline.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)
    print "linked!"

def main():
    pipeline = gst.Pipeline('pipleline')

    filesrc = gst.element_factory_make("filesrc", "filesrc")
    filesrc.set_property('location', 'C:/a.mp3')

    decode = gst.element_factory_make("decodebin", "decode")

    convert = gst.element_factory_make('audioconvert', 'convert')

    sink = gst.element_factory_make("autoaudiosink", "sink")

    pipeline.add(filesrc, decode, convert, sink)
    gst.element_link_many(filesrc, decode)
    gst.element_link_many(convert, sink)

    decode.connect("new-decoded-pad", on_new_decoded_pad)

    pipeline.set_state(gst.STATE_PAUSED)

    gtk.main()

main()
```

`gst.parse_launch` works because it takes care of all these niggly details for you. there is also the high level element `playbin` which automatically creates and links a decodebin internally.

Comment: [Decodebin](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/section-components-decodebin.html) is also explained in the GStreamer Application Development Manual.