# Playing RTSP with python-gstreamer

Tags: python, h.264, gstreamer, rtsp, ip-camera

I use gstreamer for playing RTSP stream from IP cameras (like Axis.)
I use a command line like this:

```
gst-launch-0.10 rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.0.127/axis-media/media.amp latency=0 ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

and it work fine.

I want to control it with a gui in pygtk so I use the gstreamer python bindings.
I've wrote this piece of code:

```
[...]
self.player = gst.Pipeline("player")
source = gst.element_factory_make("rtspsrc", "source")
source.set_property("location", "rtsp://192.168.0.127/axis-media/media.amp")
decoder = gst.element_factory_make("decodebin", "decoder")
sink = gst.element_factory_make("autovideosink", "sink")

self.player.add(source, decoder, sink)
gst.element_link_many(source, decoder, sink)

bus = self.player.get_bus()
bus.add_signal_watch()
bus.enable_sync_message_emission()
bus.connect("message", self.on_message)
bus.connect("sync-message::element", self.on_sync_message)
[...]
```

But it doesn't work and quit with this message:

```
gst.element_link_many(source, decoder,sink)
gst.LinkError: failed to link source with decoder
```

I've also try to improve my CLI with this as I only use h264:

```
gst-launch-0.10 -v rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.0.127/axis-media/media.amp ! rtph264depay !  ffdec_h264 ! xvimagesink
```

And implement it in my python code like that:

```
[...]
self.player = gst.Pipeline("player")
source = gst.element_factory_make("rtspsrc", "source")
depay = gst.element_factory_make("rtph264depay", "depay")
decoder = gst.element_factory_make("ffdec_h264", "decoder")
sink = gst.element_factory_make("xvimagesink", "output")

self.player.add(source, depay, decoder, sink)
gst.element_link_many(source, depay, decoder, sink)
[...]
```

But I got the same error :(

```
gst.LinkError: failed to link source with depay
```

There is something wrong between my source (rtspsrc), as it work with decodebin with a filesrc (don't work of course with rtph264depay)

I don't understand why it doesn't work because it work in cli.
Any experts of gstreamer who can help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Comment: Try the `gst_parse_launch` api call. It lets you use gst-launch syntax in your soon-to-be-much-shorter code. By naming the elements, you can set parameters as necessary without having to do string interpolation.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I already tried gst_parse_launch, but my problem is that my GstPipeline object doesn't have anymore property like location. I assume "naming the elements" (as you said) can fix my problem but I can't figure out how to do that :(

Answer (score 6):

I have a "C" implementation of the code you are looking for. I think it should be fairly simple to convert to "Python"

```
 //Display RTSP streaming of video
 //(c) 2011 enthusiasticgeek
 // This code is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 // but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 // MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  

#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <glib.h>

static gboolean bus_call (GstBus *bus,GstMessage *msg, gpointer data){
  GMainLoop *loop = (GMainLoop *) data;

  switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (msg)) {

    case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
      g_print ("Stream Ends\n");
      g_main_loop_quit (loop);
      break;

    case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR: {
      gchar  *debug;
      GError *error;

      gst_message_parse_error (msg, &error, &debug);
      g_free (debug);

      g_printerr ("Error: %s\n", error->message);
      g_error_free (error);

      g_main_loop_quit (loop);
      break;
    }
    default:
      break;
  }

  return TRUE;
}

static void on_pad_added (GstElement *element, GstPad *pad, gpointer data){

  GstPad *sinkpad;
  GstElement *decoder = (GstElement *) data;

  /* We can now link this pad with the rtsp-decoder sink pad */
  g_print ("Dynamic pad created, linking source/demuxer\n");

  sinkpad = gst_element_get_static_pad (decoder, "sink");

  gst_pad_link (pad, sinkpad);

  gst_object_unref (sinkpad);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GMainLoop *loop;
  GstBus *bus;
  GstElement *source;
  GstElement *decoder;
  GstElement *sink;
  GstElement *pipeline;
  GstElement *demux;
  GstElement *colorspace;

  /* Initializing GStreamer */
  gst_init (&argc, &argv);
  loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);

 //gst-launch-0.10 rtspsrc location=rtsp://<ip> ! decodebin ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink
 //gst-launch -v rtspsrc location="rtsp://<ip> ! rtpmp4vdepay ! mpeg4videoparse ! ffdec_mpeg4 ! ffmpegcolorspace! autovideosink
 //gst-launch -v rtspsrc location="rtsp://<ip> ! rtpmp4vdepay ! ffdec_mpeg4 ! ffmpegcolorspace! autovideosink
  /* Create Pipe's Elements */
  pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("video player");
  g_assert (pipeline);
  source   = gst_element_factory_make ("rtspsrc", "Source");
  g_assert (source);
  demux = gst_element_factory_make ("rtpmp4vdepay", "Depay");
  g_assert (demux);
  decoder = gst_element_factory_make ("ffdec_mpeg4", "Decoder");
  g_assert (decoder);
  colorspace     = gst_element_factory_make ("ffmpegcolorspace",  "Colorspace");
  g_assert(colorspace);
  sink     = gst_element_factory_make ("autovideosink", "Output");
  g_assert (sink);

  /*Make sure: Every elements was created ok*/
  if (!pipeline || !source || !demux || !decoder || !colorspace || !sink) {
    g_printerr ("One of the elements wasn't create... Exiting\n");
    return -1;
  }

  g_printf(" \nPipeline is Part(A) ->(dynamic/runtime link)  Part(B)[ Part(B-1) -> Part(B-2) -> Part(B-3) ]\n\n");
  g_printf(" [source](dynamic)->(dynamic)[demux]->[decoder]->[colorspace]->[videosink] \n\n");

  /* Set video Source */
  g_object_set (G_OBJECT (source), "location", argv[1], NULL);
  //g_object_set (G_OBJECT (source), "do-rtcp", TRUE, NULL);
  g_object_set (G_OBJECT (source), "latency", 0, NULL);

  /* Putting a Message handler */
  bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus (GST_PIPELINE (pipeline));
  gst_bus_add_watch (bus, bus_call, loop);
  gst_object_unref (bus);

  /* Add Elements to the Bin */
  gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), source, demux, decoder, colorspace, sink, NULL);

  /* Link confirmation */
  if (!gst_element_link_many (demux, decoder, colorspace, sink, NULL)){
     g_warning ("Linking part (B) Fail...");
  }

  g_printf("\nNote that the source will be linked to the demuxer(depayload) dynamically.\n\
     The reason is that rtspsrc may contain various elements (for example\n\
     audio and video). The source pad(s) will be created at run time,\n\
     by the rtspsrc when it detects the amount and nature of elements.\n\
     Therefore we connect a callback function which will be executed\n\
     when the \"pad-added\" is emitted.\n");

  /* Dynamic Pad Creation */
  if(! g_signal_connect (source, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK (on_pad_added),demux))
  {
    g_warning ("Linking part (A) with part (B) Fail...");
  }
  /* Run the pipeline */
  g_print ("Playing: %s\n", argv[1]);
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
  g_main_loop_run (loop);

  /* Ending Playback */
  g_print ("End of the Streaming... ending the playback\n");
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);

  /* Eliminating Pipeline */
  g_print ("Eliminating Pipeline\n");
  gst_object_unref (GST_OBJECT (pipeline));

  return 0;
}
```

Makefile

```
test = test12
ext = c
CC = gcc
CPP = g++
gstreamer:
    $(CC) -g $(test).$(ext) -o $(test) `pkg-config gstreamer-0.10 --libs --cflags` `pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --libs --cflags`
clean:
    rm -rf $(test)
```

**UPDATE**

Equivalent Java Code

```
 // Display RTSP streaming of video
 // (c) 2011 enthusiasticgeek
 // This code is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 // but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 // MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
 // Leave Credits intact

package video2; //replace this with your package
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

//import org.gstreamer.Caps;
import org.gstreamer.Element;
import org.gstreamer.ElementFactory;
import org.gstreamer.Gst;
import org.gstreamer.Pad;
import org.gstreamer.PadDirection;
import org.gstreamer.Pipeline;
import org.gstreamer.swing.VideoComponent;

/**
 * A Simple videotest example.
 */
public class Main {
    public Main() {
    }
    private static Pipeline pipe;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Quartz is abysmally slow at scaling video for some reason, so turn it off.
    System.setProperty("apple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz", "false");

    args = Gst.init("SwingVideoTest", args);

    pipe = new Pipeline("pipeline");
    /*
    final Element videosrc = ElementFactory.make("videotestsrc", "source");
    final Element videofilter = ElementFactory.make("capsfilter", "flt");
    videofilter.setCaps(Caps.fromString("video/x-raw-yuv, width=720, height=576"
            + ", bpp=32, depth=32, framerate=25/1"));
    */

     pipe.getBus().connect(new Bus.ERROR() {
        public void errorMessage(GstObject source, int code, String message) {
            System.out.println("Error occurred: " + message);
            Gst.quit();
        }
    });
    pipe.getBus().connect(new Bus.STATE_CHANGED() {
        public void stateChanged(GstObject source, State old, State current, State pending) {
            if (source == pipe) {
                System.out.println("Pipeline state changed from " + old + " to " + current);
            }
        }
    });
    pipe.getBus().connect(new Bus.EOS() {
        public void endOfStream(GstObject source) {
            System.out.println("Finished playing file");
            Gst.quit();
        }
    });        

     pipe.getBus().connect(new Bus.TAG() {
        public void tagsFound(GstObject source, TagList tagList) {
            for (String tag : tagList.getTagNames()) {
                System.out.println("Found tag " + tag + " = "
                        + tagList.getValue(tag, 0));
            }
        }
    });

    final Element source = ElementFactory.make("rtspsrc", "Source");
    final Element demux = ElementFactory.make("rtpmp4vdepay", "Depay");
    final Element decoder=ElementFactory.make("ffdec_mpeg4", "Decoder");
    final Element colorspace = ElementFactory.make("ffmpegcolorspace",  "Colorspace");
    //final Element sink = ElementFactory.make ("autovideosink", "Output");

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            // Create the video component and link it in
            VideoComponent videoComponent = new VideoComponent();
            Element videosink = videoComponent.getElement();

           source.connect(new Element.PAD_ADDED() {
           public void padAdded(Element element, Pad pad) {
            pad.link(demux.getStaticPad("sink"));
           }
            });

           Pad p = new Pad(null, PadDirection.SRC);
           source.addPad(p);

            source.set("location","rtsp://<user>:<pass>@<ip>/mpeg4/1/media.amp");  //replace this with your source

            pipe.addMany(source, demux, decoder, colorspace, videosink);
            Element.linkMany(demux, decoder, colorspace, videosink);

            // Now create a JFrame to display the video output
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swing Video Test");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(videoComponent, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            videoComponent.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(720, 576));
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);

            // Start the pipeline processing
            pipe.play();
        }
    });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer explains why you get a `gst.LinkError`: [Gstreamer of python's gst.LinkError problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993777/gstreamer-of-pythons-gst-linkerror-problem/3041321#3041321)

With `gst.parse_launch`, you can name elements and then retrieve them to set properties:

```
pipeline = gst.parse_launch('rtspsrc name=source latency=0 ! decodebin ! autovideosink')
source = pipeline.get_by_name('source')
source.props.location = 'rtsp://192.168.0.127/axis-media/media.amp'
```

Comment: May I ask what the complete source.props.location Is necessary to RTSP DESCRIBE an Axis camera which supports H264?