# Setting gstreamer capsfilter with OpenCV in c++

Tags: c++, opencv, webcam, gstreamer, frame-rate

With the Microsoft LifeCam Cinema (on Ubuntu) in guvcview I get 30fps on 1280x720. In my OpenCV program, I only get 10fps (only `queryframe` and `showimage`, no image processing is done). I found out that it is a [*problem* in gstreamer](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=676093). A solution is to set a capsfilter in gstreamer, in terminal I can do it like this:

```
gst-launch v4l2src device=/dev/video0 !
'video/x-raw-yuv,width=1280,height=720,framerate=30/1' ! xvimagesink
```

This works! The question is:

1. How do I implement this in my c++/OpenCV program?
2. Or is it possible to set gstreamer to always use this capsfilter?

I already found this question [Option 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7084081/1383972), but I can't get it working with a webcam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, I was setting my webcam to 1280x800, which forces it to use YUVY with max 10 fps. Setting it back to 1280x720 in my program gave me 30 fps

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to set the format (YUV) of the frames retrieved from the camera, but for the rest of the settings you could try using [`cvSetCaptureProperty()`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#setcaptureproperty):

```
cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 30);
cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280);
cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720);
```

If setting the frame size doesn't work, I strongly suggest you read this post: [Increasing camera capture resolution in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287/increasing-camera-capture-resolution-in-opencv)

Comment: Thank you, but CV_CAP_PROP_FPS is a non working function in OpenCV. Also it isn't an OpenCV problem, it is a gstreamer problem (see bug report)

Comment: If the above doesn't work you are out of luck. You won't be able to set the pipeline configs through OpenCV.