# How to get fps from video in java?

Tags: java, opencv, video, frame-rate

I have some task to do video processing and I want to do it with openCV and java.

The problem is when I didn't do much process there the video runs so fast. On the other hand when there is plenty thing to do with the video, the video runs so slow on my program. I got an idea to do something with the fps and then I only get [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070528/opencv-dramatically-increase-frame-rate-from-playback) and still wonder **how to get fps from video in java** with or without openCV.

any help will be appreciated, especially if you can solve my root problem  :)

Comment: `double fps = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)`

Comment: Unfortunately in [here](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/highgui/VideoCapture.html) there were only CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH and CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT option, neither FPS can be found [here](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/highgui/Highgui.html).
it can only be found [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-get) in C++ OpenCV

Comment: after a short research, it may be a bug. Try `cap.get(5);`

Comment: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/4667

Comment: yeah it worked.
on my video that has 29 fps it says 29.97002997002997

Comment: do OpenCV in java are that bad?  should I move to C++? what about JavaCV?

Comment: I personally use and prefer C++. Java and Python bindings work ok generally, some bug may happen. JavaCV is not recommended since it's not official nor well supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For OpenCV 3 the constants for the fps, width, height, etc are in VideoIO. In other words, you have to use:

```
cap.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FPS);
cap.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
cap.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
```

Comment: Have you tried CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH and HEIGHT?
I need it recently and when I use it, both of them turn out to return the width of the video. Maybe it's a bug?

Comment: Uh okay I have tried it with another video and it works fine actually.
Only for just this [video](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/dshmg0cnoup8wgq/AACVHl6LnNgSKgTvnYY3B_56a/visiontraffic.avi?dl=0) it's become 640x640. Actually it's 360x640. Can you try it for me?

Comment: I get 640x640 as well for that.