# gstreamer: could not add element

Tags: gstreamer, python-gstreamer

I am trying to stream a video from an android phone to my laptop. I ran the gstreamer and it works fine. My problem is with the following code:

```
   [....]
    pipeline = gst.parse_launch('rtspsrc name=source latency=0 ! decodebin ! autovideosink')
    source = pipeline.get_by_name('source')
    source.props.location =  "rtsp://128.237.119.100:8086/"
    decoder = gst.element_factory_make("decodebin", "decoder")
    sink = gst.element_factory_make("autovideosink", "sink")

    pipeline.add(source, decoder, sink)
    gst.element_link_many(source, decoder, sink)
    [...]
```

I get this error when I run it:

```
      (server.py:2893): GStreamer-WARNING **: Name 'source' is not unique in bin 'pipeline0', not adding
       Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "server.py", line 27, in <module>
       py = pyserver()
       File "server.py", line 18, in __init__
       pipeline.add(source, decoder, sink)
       gst.AddError: Could not add element 'source'
```

I am new to gstreamer. I have referred to this question to write the code: [Playing RTSP with python-gstreamer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192871/playing-rtsp-with-python-gstreamer)

Could anyone please point out what I am doing wrong? Why do I get the adderror?

Comment: This looks like you added source element somewhere before. I suggest you try without parse_launch element - try to make each element separately, add to pipeline and link them. Check return of every command and it will be easy to debug it.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to add the element source to the pipeline again. It is already added.

Comment: This is correct, `gst_parse_launch` adds the elements to the pipeline.  Performing a `pipeline.add(source)` will attempt to add the element again and fail.

Answer (score 1):

From gstreamer **gst_pipeline_add_many()** documentation:

> Adds a NULL-terminated list of elements to a bin.

So it's should be:

```
gst.element_link_many(source, decoder, sink, NULL);
```