# How to use gstreamer in aiortc?

Tags: webrtc, gstreamer, rtsp, aiortc

I'm a beginner trying to understand GStreamer yet, but a little boilerplate on using GStreamer for rtspsrc to aiortc python module for WebRTC would be quite helpful as I couldn't find any good example.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192871/playing-rtsp-with-python-gstreamer?rq=1) should help

Comment: I forgot to mention that I was able to display the stream using parse_launch with autovideosink from rtspsrc. But I was confused on how to use the pipeline for other purpose (in my case webrtc).  So after seeing the link that you have provided, I'm still not sure but see if I'm correct, instead of using autovideosink we try appsink with a name and later we can capture it using pipeline.get_by_name() method and use it in webrtc local/remote stream? Anyways thanks for your reply!

Comment: Also recently I came across webrtcbin (still trying understand it), will it be any useful here? If so how to use it